# Cannot find pylint in git actions

Tags: python, git, github, github-actions, pylint

Trying to run a pylint action in my build on github but it says it cannot find pylint.

Code

```
  linting:
    name: PyLint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: install
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: pip3 install -U pip setuptools
      - run: pip3 install -U -r requirements.txt
      - run: export PATH=/home/runner/.local/bin/$PATH
      - run: pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc src/
```

Error

```
Run pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc src/
/home/runner/work/_temp/44ccfc48-998a-405a-b25a-20b24f532ea1.sh: line 1: pylint: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

I tried add it to my PATH as I was getting this message on the pip install

```
WARNING: The scripts epylint, pylint, pyreverse and symilar are installed in '/home/runner/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
```

But this did not help the issue.

Comment: do you have pylint in requirements.txt?

Comment: Yeah pylint==2.6.0 and its being installed in the logs of the pip install

Comment: this is a typo: `export PATH=/home/runner/.local/bin/$PATH` -- it should be `export PATH=/home/runner/.local/bin/:$PATH`  (note the `:`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems python is not configured properly. You need to add [`actions/setup-python`](https://github.com/actions/setup-python) step at the beginning of your workflow in order to get it properly set-up. Try to remove the line

```
- run: export PATH=/home/runner/.local/bin/$PATH`
```

and add

```
- uses: actions/setup-python@v2
```

just before calling `pip`

```
linting:
    name: PyLint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: install
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      - run: pip3 install -U pip setuptools
      - run: pip3 install -U -r requirements.txt
      - run: pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc src/
```

This should do the trick.